# VIM script to remove Ghost newlines

Tags: linux, vim

Is there any way using either Vim scripting or search/replace to remove ghost newlines? I have come across times when I have to edit files that other developers using crappy software have left double newlines in like the attached picture.

I would love to find a way in Vim to remove all those stupid double spacing junk so it actually looks like it should.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running the search-and-replace

```
%s/\n\n/\r/g
```

will replace every pair of two newlines with a single one. This will inevitably screw up files that aren't already double-spaced, though, so don't use it blindly.

Answer (score 4):

Shorter solution:

```
:v:.:d
```

It those lines are really empty. If there might be white spaces:

```
:v:^\S*$:d
```

Comment: I tend to think in positives so would go with `:g/^\s*$/d` but the end result is the same.  This is a nice solution and `:global` and `:vglobal` are great commands to know.